# java generics of Collection<T> that returns either List<T> or Set<T>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm trying to write a class that implements Enumeration> in such a way that I get back not Collection, but either Set or List... according to what I'd like to get.

I'd like to be able to use the following syntax:

```
Enumeration<Set<Integer>> setEn =
    new CollectionEnumeration<Integer, Set<Integer>>(ids, HashSet.class);
```

or:

```
Enumeration<Set<Integer>> setEn =
    new CollectionEnumeration<Integer, Set>(ids, HashSet.class);
```

or:

```
Enumeration<List<Integer>> listEn =
    new CollectionEnumeration<Integer, List<Integer>>(ids, ArrayList.class);
```

or:

```
Enumeration<List<Integer>> listEn =
    new CollectionEnumeration<Integer, List>(ids, LinkedList.class);
```

What is the correct way to declare the class?

This is what I have so far:

```
class CollectionEnumeration<T, Coll extends Collection<T>> implements Enumeration<Coll> {
    final private List<List<T>> stopListZoneIds;
    final private Class<? extends Coll> klass;
    final private int[] index;
    final private int max;
    private int current;
    private int stopIndex;

    CollectionEnumeration(List<List<T>> stopListZoneIds, Class<? extends Coll> klass) {
        this.stopListZoneIds = stopListZoneIds;
        this.klass = klass;
        int all = 1;
        index = new int[stopListZoneIds.size()];
        for (int stopIdx = 0; stopIdx < stopListZoneIds.size(); stopIdx++) {
            index[stopIdx] = 0;
            all *= stopListZoneIds.get(stopIdx).size();
        }
        max = all;
        current = 0;
        stopIndex = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return current < max;
    }

    @Override
    public Coll nextElement() {
        if (!hasMoreElements()) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Coll collection = klass.newInstance();
            for (int stopIdx = 0; stopIdx < stopListZoneIds.size(); stopIdx++) {
                collection.add(stopListZoneIds.get(stopIdx).get(index[stopIdx]));
            }
            doStep();
            return collection;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void doStep() {
        if (current >= max) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Shouldn't call doStep() when !hasMoreElements()");
        }
        do {
            if (index[stopIndex] < stopListZoneIds.get(stopIndex).size()) {
                index[stopIndex]++;
                current++;
                return;
            } else {
                index[stopIndex] = 0;
                stopIndex++;
            }
        } while(stopIndex < stopListZoneIds.size());
        current++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you boil this down, I answered an almost identical question 2 days ago. The issue is that `Class<? extends Coll>` => `Class<? extends Collection<T>>` and `HashMap.class` does not satisfy that constraint (in fact, nothing does). You should not pass the class anyway, pass a constructor via method reference (a `Supplier<Coll>`)

Comment: Thanks, that really helped!

Comment: Sure, no problem.